# Internal HDD VS External HDD startup

Tags: macos, startup

I have a 20" early 2008 iMac, I upgraded the Hardrive and using an external USB connector installed a fresh OS (Lion 10.7.5) and it starts up and runs fine externally. However when i put it in the computer using the internal connections I only get a blinking folder icon. If I put the original HD it starts up and works fine so I'm thinking its not a physical problem in the case. Anybody have any ideas??

Comment: Have you gone to the System Preferences and set the new disk as the startup disk?

Comment: Yes I have Christian, it starts up fine externally, but not internally, even if it is the only disc.

Comment: I would assume you put the new drive in an shell to connect externally to the Mac. What is the model of the new drive and the shell? Sometimes the disk can have a 4k byte sector size, but the shell can convert this back to a legacy 512 byte sector size. So, when the drive is inserted internally, the drive will not boot.

Comment: If the internal disk is bad and being replaced, why would not install the new disk internally first and then boot the Mac from an OS X Installer and then install the OS? I see no good reason to do it in the manner you have!

Comment: I used a USB 2.0 Drivemate, just clips on to the disk. The drive is a 1TB Seagate. Formatted Extended

Answer (score 1):

When you have the new HDD installed in the computer you should be holding down the option key when you boot the machine.  This will bring you to the startup manager and allow you to choose to boot from any drive connected that has a bootable OS installed.  Select the internal HDD.  Once you get to the desktop open System Preferences > Startup Disk  and permanently choose that drive to boot from.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417

If the drive does not show up in the Startup Manager, then you have a problem.

Comment: If there's only one bootable volume connected, a Mac will just boot from it if it can. You only get the question mark when it's exhausted all possibilities.

Comment: I have tried putting the new one in and using the startup manager, all I get is the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the drive using "GPT (GUID Partition Map)"

It will not boot otherwise.

Comment: Formatting through Disk Utility gives the following options only....: OS X Extended, (Journaled), OS X Extended, (Case Sensitive Journaled), OS X Extended, (Journaled), MS-Dos FAT and ExFAT.........

Comment: In the info window it indicates Guid.........

Comment: The part that gets me the new drive boots externally, but not internally, the old drive will startup internally but not externally..............